# Custom ReplayKit PreviewViewController View

Tags: replaykit

I'm very new to ReplayKit and trying out some features with it. When the stop recording function is called replaykit shows up a previewview for user to cancel or save the video. I wonder if you change the UI of this view and customize it. If anybody did it before it would be awesome to see some samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customise the `previewController`, but you may use "Photos", a powerful kit from apple to access video/photo from users' photo library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. But you will have to use other methods of ReplayKit.

You will call `RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder.startCaptureWithHandler()` and save frame by frame to a video file using AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput.
When you will call `RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder.stopCaptureWithHandler()` you can finish writing the AVAssetWriter and the video will be saved on your specified place.
After that you can show custom prompt.

It is not as straight forward as `startRecording()` and `stopRecording()`.
Let me know if you need more help